# Record xls and xlsx file location from zip file extracted

Tags: python, excel

The code below unzips a file and places it in a directory. There are times when the zip files has folders with in the zip.

The code works my issue is that I need to also as I extract these zip files and record the complete path of all xls and xlsx files into a dataframe so I can iterate through dataframe and convert to csv.
Any ideas i have tried to store the file path in a df but have not been successful

```
processlist = sqldf[sqldf['filename'].isin(newlist)]

for file in processlist['filename']:
    source = rootpath + file
    dest = rootext + file.replace('.zip','')+"/"
    print(source)
    print(dest)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(source,'r') as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall(dest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you loop all the files and folders in your destination folder?

You could use os.walk for that task. See:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm

Comment: Well i have a function that finds the xls file, but it has issues with formation of path. Not sure whats going on Here is code

Comment: def recursive_glog(treeroot,pattern):
    results = []
    for base, dirs, files in os.walk(treeroot, topdown=True):
        goodfiles = fnmatch.filter(files, pattern)
        results.extend(os.path.join(base, f) for f in goodfiles)
    return results

recursive_glog(dest,'*.xls')

Comment: ['//RootFolder/datafeeds/CMS_ResearchStatistics/UnZipStageFile/monthly-contract-summary-report-april-2020/Monthly_Summary_Report_2020_04\\Monthly_Summary_Report_2020_04.xls']

Comment: Notice initially the slashes  "/" for source variable entered then when it finds match it returns rest of the path "\". I t also adds "\\" at the beginning. I need to get to this path and this path wont work its not constructed correctly

Comment: You can use os.join to join multiple paths. It will use the separator depending on your os.

Comment: Yes, i did use the os command to join and it does join but at the end I have a path with 2 different separators. in one case it even has 2 separators together. How can i just have 1?